# How to wallet sync with blockchain network

Tags: wallets

I'm newbie, I have question: when a wallet connect to a network blockchain, does it connect to ALL of node in network or SOME node? And how to a wallet sync blockchain ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. connect to some nodes.

there are some special nodes run by Ethereum foundation.

When a wallet get started, it tries to connect those nodes

and of course, it tries to add random peers

2. as you know, Ethereum use P2P.

download data from connecting peers or broadcast data to peers.

when Ethereum node select peers, it use [Kademlia peer selection algorithm](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Kademlia-Peer-Selection)